# R: expand dataframe by pairing values within a minimum criteria

Tags: r

I have a dataframe comprising two columns ("delta" & "let"). Values within "let" represent unique factors. Values within "delta" represent any integer between 0–1000000.

Sample dataframe (df) below:

```
df <- data.frame(delta = c(0,6,2,3,4,8,6,1,1,4),
                 let   = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"))

df
     delta let
1      0   a
2      6   b
3      2   c
4      3   d
5      4   e
6      8   f
7      6   g
8      1   h
9      1   i
10     4   j
```

**To explain df**: the integer within "delta" denotes the difference in time (minutes) between sequential factors within "let". For instance, "b" has a 6 minute time difference from "a", "c" has a 2 minute time difference from "b", and "d" has a 3 minute time difference from "c" ... etc.

I'd like to generate a new data frame (df2) that "pairs" values of "let" based on a minimum time difference (minDelta ≤ 2 minutes); resulting in the following output:

```
minDelta <- 2 # minutes

df2
    let    let.pairs
1    a        NA
2    b         c
3    c         b
4    d        NA
5    e        NA
6    f        NA
7    g         h
8    g         i
9    h         g
10   h         i
11   i         g
12   i         h
13   j        NA
```

**To explain df2**: "a" doesn't pair with any other value within "let" given a minimum time difference criterion of ≤ minDelta. Hence, "let.pairs" for "a" is "NA". Conversely, "b" pairs with "c" (and vice versa) because their time difference (delta = 2) is ≤ minDelta. Importantly, note that "g" pairs with "h" (delta = 1) and with "i" (delta = 1+1).

I'd appreciate any assistance with the R code to achieve the stated objective.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option

```
x <- setNames(cumsum(df$delta), df$let)

pairs <- NULL
for (lag in seq(length(x) - 1L)) {
    tmp <- which(diff(x, lag) <= minDelta) + lag
    if (length(tmp))
        pairs[[lag]] <- cbind(names(x)[tmp], names(x)[tmp - lag])
    else
        break
}
pairs <- do.call(rbind, pairs)
pairs <- rbind(pairs, pairs[, c(2, 1)])
pairs <- rbind(pairs, cbind(setdiff(names(x), pairs[, 1]), NA))
pairs <- pairs[order(pairs[, 1]), ]
data.frame(let=pairs[, 1], let.pairs=pairs[, 2])
#   let let.pairs
#1    a      <NA>
#2    b         c
#3    c         b
#4    d      <NA>
#5    e      <NA>
#6    f      <NA>
#7    g         h
#8    g         i
#9    h         g
#10   h         i
#11   i         h
#12   i         g
#13   j      <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a recursive function to approach the problem:

```
find.pair <- function(df) {
    if(nrow(df) == 0) data.frame()
    else {
        pairs = df$let[c(F, cumsum(df$delta[-1]) <= 2)]
        if(length(pairs) == 0) {
            rbind(data.frame(let = df$let[1], let.pairs = NA),
                  find.pair(df[-1,]))
        }
        else {
            rbind(data.frame(let = df$let[1], 
                             let.pairs = pairs), 
                  data.frame(let = pairs,
                             let.pairs = df$let[1]),
                  find.pair(df[-1,]))    
        }
    }
}
```

This does not give you exactly what you need, but it is an idea. Tweaking with the result data frame a little bit should give you the desired result.

```
find.pair(df)
#    let let.pairs
# 1    a      <NA>
# 2    b         c
# 3    c         b
# 4    c      <NA>
# 5    d      <NA>
# 6    e      <NA>
# 7    f      <NA>
# 8    g         h
# 9    g         i
# 10   h         g
# 11   i         g
# 12   h         i
# 13   i         h
# 14   i      <NA>
# 15   j      <NA>
```